# How to declare optional arguments in proc

Tags: tcl

Could you help me how to use arguments with optionals I used this function but it does not work

```
proc {my_proc} {n1 n2 -args{{u2 "5"} {u1 "5"}} } {

puts "n1:'$n1', n2:'$n2', u1:'$u1', u2:'$u2'"
}

->my_proc 1 -args 5 7
n1:'1', n2:'$n2', u1:'7', u2:'5'
```

I would like to call function like

1. `my_proc 1 -args {u2 5} {u1 7}`
2. `my_proc 1  {u2 5} {u1 7}  (required + optional arguments)`
3. `my_proc 1 (only required arguments)`

Comment: In that case, use `args` as last parameter name and parse the content of that list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are ***strongly recommended*** to use only one of these patterns in a particular command:

1. Optional arguments, where the optional-ness is by position.
2. Optional key-value pairs.

Combining the two is relatively hard to get right, and is always rather confusing!

### Optional by position

```
proc my_proc {n1 n2 {u2 "5"} {u1 "5"}} {
    puts "n1:'$n1', n2:'$n2', u1:'$u1', u2:'$u2'"
}
my_proc 7 8 9
#### n1:'7', n2:'8', u1:'5', u2:'9'
```

### Optionality by key-value pair

```
proc my_proc {n1 n2 args} {
    # Add the defaults
    set args [dict merge {-u1 5 -u2 5} $args]
    # Magic! (Keys start with “-” by arbitrary convention.)
    # Copies from the value for key “-u1” to $u1 (and similarly “-u2”/$u2)
    # The empty value is an update script; empty here as we don't want to update
    dict update args  -u1 u1  -u2 u2  {}

    # Use...
    puts "n1:'$n1', n2:'$n2', u1:'$u1', u2:'$u2'"
}
my_proc 7 8 -u1 123 -u2 456
#### n1:'7', n2:'8', u1:'123', u2:'456'
```

There's a few other ways to do this, e.g., with `dict set options $args;puts $options(-u1)`. These are particularly useful in Tcl 8.4 (and before, for the truly behind-the-times):

```
proc my_proc {n1 n2 args} {
    # Defaults
    array set opt {-u1 5 -u2 5}
    # Parse
    array set opt $args
    # Use
    puts "n1:'$n1', n2:'$n2', u1:'$opt(-u1)', u2:'$opt(-u2)'"
}
my_proc 7 8 -u1 123 -u2 456
#### n1:'7', n2:'8', u1:'123', u2:'456'
```

Comment: I tried the above one but in my tclversion it shwoing Error: invalid command name "dict" (TCL)

Comment: @user3069844 No `dict`? You must have a very old version of Tcl.

Comment: i am using tclversion 8.4 in designer tool

Answer (score 0):

As Donal suggested, I like to use `args` and an array to handle options. It allows an easy way to set default values:

```
proc p {args} {
    array set options {-u1 defU1 -u2 defU2}  ;# the default values
    array set options $args                  ;# merge the user's values
    parray options
}
p -foo bar -u1 42
```

```
options(-foo) = bar
options(-u1)  = 42
options(-u2)  = defU2
```

You will need to check that $args contains an even number of elements:

```
% p 1 2 3
list must have an even number of elements
```